# Loop an animation idiomatically

Tags: angular

I'm working in Angular, and I have an animation on a component that I'd like to loop until a notification comes in from elsewhere.

```
    animations: [
    trigger('boxState', [
        state('begin', style({
            width: '100%',
        })),
        state('end', style({
            width: '0%',
        })),
        transition('end => begin', animate('2500ms')),
        transition('begin => end', animate('0ms'))
    ])
]
```

I can make the animation loop by listening for the `start` and `done` events on the animation and changing the `boxState` manually as appropriate.

```
<div [@boxState]="boxState" (@boxState.start)="animationStarted($event)" (@boxState.done)="animationEnded($event)" ></div>
```

However, this seems like an oddly imperative way of working that goes against Angular's usual declarative idioms. Is there a more idiomatic way of looping an animation that I'm missing?

Comment: https://angular-animations-demo.firebaseapp.com/loop-demo

Comment: Here is source code :https://github.com/leonardopaiva/angular-animation-basic-project/tree/master/src/app/loop-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to write code for you but I am giving you the source from where you can solve your problem.

Source Code : https://github.com/leonardopaiva/angular-animation-basic-project/tree/master/src/app/loop-demo

Demo Link https://angular-animations-demo.firebaseapp.com/loop-demo

If you find any error in following this then come back here

**Happy Coding**

Comment: Thank you. This confirmed that what I was already doing (setting up another trigger from the "done" callback) is the go-to way of doing it, and I'm not missing anything.